# What can we say about the class of $x\equiv y\Leftrightarrow x=y$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My lecture notes say that the class of this has one element, i.e.,$\left[ x\right] =\left\{ x\right\}$. Why? Can you explain?

Comment: Suppose it had more than one element.  Then there are at least two different elements., call them $x\in [x]$ and $y\in [x]$.  That implies since they both belong to the same class that they are "equivalent", i.e. $x\equiv y$.  But by the definition given for equivalent in this context, that implies that $x=y$, and we see that they are in fact not different elements at all but the same element.

Comment: Did you mean to ask:  For all $x, y \in \mathbb Z$, $x\equiv y \iff x= y$.?

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I did.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of equivalence class: $$[x]\underbrace{=}_{\text{def}}\{y\in\mathbb{Z}:y\equiv x\}=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}:y=x\}=\{x\}.$$